# Unicode characters (emoji) not displayed when knitting to PDF

Tags: pdf, knitr, emoji

I'm working on a Mac and have an R script file. My data frame has the variable "content", a character string that includes emoji

```
 "This is amazing!  "
```

The following code does not display emoji, but only a combination of numbers and letters:

```
head(x$content)
print(x$content[1])

 "This is amazing \U0001f4aa\U0001f4aa "
```

However, once I make use of kable, it displays the emoji in my console

later the emoji is not displayed when I knit the document to PDF:

```
kable( x[, "content"])
```

Do I need a special font or a special Latex package that will allow me to knit the document to PDF and display the emojis?

Comment: Nina it's hard to help you without a reproducible example.

Comment: It seems like I cannot upload my data file. But I have a character string with the following content: "This is amazing!  "
If I do head(x$content), then this will appear: "This is amazing \U0001f4aa\U0001f4aa "
With kable( x[, "content"]) I get to see the emoji, but when knitting to PDF, the number combination appears. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that you are using pdflatex, and your character is a unicode character, which is not supported by pdflatex.

Depending on the encoding of your system you have to use

```
enc2utf8(enc2native("This is amazing! "))
```

or simply

```
iconv("This is amazing! ","Unicode","UTF-8")
```

*In my case the latter does not work as I'm on a system with `latin1` encoding*

Does that solves your problem ?

Comment: Using the first version, I get this in my PDF: 
## [1] "This is amazing! \U0001f4aa\U0001f4aa"

I cannot run the second version. It gives me this error:
Error in iconv("This is amazing! \U0001f4aa\U0001f4aa", "Unicode", "UTF-8") : 
  unsupported conversion from 'Unicode' to 'UTF-8'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> iconv
Execution halted

Comment: Sorry for that, the conversion worked on windows. It's hard for me to replicate your problem. What do you have with Encoding(x$content[1])  ? Try converting from that format to UTF8.